# How to generate and use the generated file

Tags: ocaml, ocp-build

Is it possible, with ocp-build, to do the following actions:

1. Compile a generator.
2. Call the generator to generate a file.
3. Compile the project with the generated file.

So far, I tried this:

(generator.ocp)

```
begin library "error_gen"
    sort = true
    files = [ "error_gen.ml" ]
    requires = [str]
end
```

(generated.ocp)

```
begin library "error_code"
    sort = true
    files = [
      "error_code.ml" (
        pp = [ "./_obuild/error_gen/error_gen.byte" ]
        pp_requires = [ "error_gen:byte" ]
      )
    ]
    requires = ["error_gen"]
end
```

(and the main.ocp)

```
begin program "main"
    sort = true
    files = []
    requires = ["error_code" "parser"]
end
```

It complains with this message:

> Error: in project "error_code", the source filename
>   "src/generated/error_code.ml" does not exist

I saw that some supports exist for version file generation, such as in the project [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent/blob/master/src/ocp-indent.ocp)

line 46.

```
"indentVersion.ml" (ocp2ml) (* auto-generated by ocp-build *)
```

Any helps greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible at this moment. I will be very   suprised if it is already supported. I think, that the better place to ask about this project is its bug tracker on github....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In branch "next" of github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-build, you will find a version of ocp-build that might solve your issue:

```
begin library "error_code"
    sort = true
    files = [ "error_code.ml" ]
    build_rules = [
      "error_code.ml" (
        (* the files that are needed to call the command *)
        sources = [ "%{error_gen_FULL_DST_DIR}%/error_gen.byte" ]
        (* the commands to be executed, in the sub-directory of the library
           each command has the syntax:    { "COMMAND" "ARG1" "ARG2" ... }
        *)
        commands = [ 
           {   "%{error_gen_FULL_DST_DIR}%/error_gen.byte"   } 
        ]
      )
    ]
    requires = ["error_gen"]
end
```

This is, for example, used in wxOCaml:

https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocplib-wxOCaml/blob/next-ocpbuild/configure.ocp

Commands can be post-fixed with options:

```
{ "configure" } (chdir = "subdirectory")  (* to execute in a sub-directory *)
{ "cat" "toto" } (stdout = "new_toto")    (* to copy the stdout in "new_toto" *)
```

Comment: That's good to know that such a feature will be available, however I can't use this version so I'll use a Makefile on top of ocp-build.